# отправить запрос php обработчику другого домена и получить json ответ

Tags: php, ajax, cors

Вопрос вот в чем
Есть работающий калькулятор
Но нужно сделать так, чтобы обработчик был на одном домене, а форма на другом.
Все это на мастерхост (если имеет значение)

Вот эта функция собирает и отправляет данные из формы в обработчик другого домена

```
$(function(){
var ajax_timeout=false, 
delay_beforesend=300;
function sendForm(){
$.ajax({url:'http://example.ru/utilite/calc/calc-function.php',
data:$('form').serialize(),
dataType: "json",
method:'post',
success: function(response).......
```

Вот эта возвращает ответ, (должно бы возвращать)

```
echo json_encode(array(
'metr_sebest'    => $metr_sebest,
'shebenka'       => $shebenka,
'amount'         => $amount,......
```

Как это реализовать кроссдоменно? Не хочется делится кодом обработчика, нужно чтобы обработчик оставался за кадром

Comment: Используй библиотеку CURL, она позволяет обмениваться данными кроссдоменно

Comment: Увидеть бы пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запросе данных указывайте тип данных jsonp, иначе крос-доменный запрос работать не будет

```
$(function(){
var ajax_timeout=false, 
delay_beforesend=300;
function sendForm(){
$.ajax({url:'http://example.ru/utilite/calc/calc-function.php',
data:$('form').serialize(),
dataType: "jsonp",
method:'post',
success: function(response).
```

На стороне сервера оберните ответ в callback функцию

```
echo  $_GET['callback'] . '(' .json_encode($responseData) . ')';
```

Comment: Замечательно, все работает, но как сделать чтобы запросы разрешались только с определенных хостов?

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы браузер не блокировал кроссдоменные запросы, вам нужно со своей стороны отдавать http заголовки, где foo.bar домен\зона вызывающей стороны. Так же можно использовать "*" (разрешено всем)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.bar
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
```

Убедитесь, что при запросе к вам ajax отправляет заголовок

```
Origin: http://foo.example
```

Другой вариант, сделать доп. обработчик на стороне "вашего клиента"
который будет делать запрос к вам, средствами cURL, или file_get_contents и возвращать результат ответа на фронтенд